# Multiple passport strategy with the same user entity

Tags: authentication, nestjs, passport.js

Google authentication gives me a profile contain a user name email and profile pic for example and that is the same for most of provider but in case of local authentication I need to store the user password what is the shape of the user entity in this case.

I have tried to make different entities but that did not go well.